# How to sell Mp3/mp4 in Magento without damning the server

Tags: magento-1.9

I want  to sell mp3 and Mp4 in Magento but I think it would make make server is quickly full

Any suggestion for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge selling music is outside of a scope Magento was originally built for. Not sure whether you will offer potential customers streaming/listening option prior to making a purchase. If you do, it will usually require a good Dedicated server with high bandwidth, nevertheless Magento itself is a resource hungry beast.

Look into Adobe Media server, possibly Wowza Media.

-my two cents.

Comment: Yeah youre right , its need more space I think I can use  third party like mediafire or etc ?